# Problem executing a cron job under Ubuntu 16

Tags: cron

I've a problem executing cron job.

The Php file works perfectly. It's create a simple .txt file.

The error I have is the following:

```
Failed loading cf:  cf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What it means please ?

Thanks.

Comment: `No such file or directory`